# Updating d3 line graph shows incorrect data, perhaps due to path transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Thanks to the path transitions tutorials ([here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1643051)) from Mike Bostock, I have cobbled together a working graph that updates using d3. However, when it goes from point to point the graph seems to misrepresent the values for those points. Below is a visual example. As you'll see the values go:

`0, -1, -4, -4, 4, -2, -2, 0 , -3`

But the graph doesn't convey that pattern. Instead it looks more like:

`0, -1, -4, 2, -2, -1, -3`

[image]

Here's a jsfiddle with my code that produces the above (but with different values): http://jsfiddle.net/q5onmfbd/9/

Does anyone have an idea as to what could be happening? I have a feeling it deals with path transitions but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [interpolation is using](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate) "basis" - this is a b-spline - it smooths and fits "around" your points.

Did you mean to use a "linear" [interpolation](http://jsfiddle.net/q5onmfbd/11/)?

```
line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear").x((d) ->
  x(new Date(formatDate(d.created_at)))
).y((d) ->
  y(d.value)
)
```